# Why are Active Directory password resets ignoring the Password History Count rule?

Tags: active-directory, powershell, group-policy, password-reset

I have a situation whereby an AD domain I am working with has a sensible enough password policy in place (e.g., sufficiently high `PasswordHistoryCount`, `MinPasswordLength` settings etc.). I can change a given user's password via PowerShell easily enough using the `Set-ADAccountPassword` cmdlet, like so:

```
Set-ADAccountPassword
    -Identity "Forename.Surname"
    -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "incorrectp0nypetrolnail" -Force)
    -OldPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "correcth0rsebatterystaple" -Force)
```

The above also raises an `ADPasswordComplexityException` expection when the password policy is violated when attempting to re-use a password, i.e., with the message:

```
"The password does not meet the length, complexity, or history requirement of the domain."
```

However, the password history policy is not being enforced when passwords are reset. This occurs either when using the "Active Directory Users and Computers" UI, or when using the `Set-ADAccountPassword` cmdlet like so (assume the password below has been  previously used by the user):

```
Set-ADAccountPassword
    -Identity "Forename.Surname"
    -Reset
    -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "correcth0rsebatterystaple" -Force)
```

I would have expected the same `ADPasswordComplexityException` exception to have been raised in this situation.

So - is there any way to prevent a user from reusing passwords when a password reset is made? If not, what are sensible reasons for allowing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the expected behavior and is by design.  Administrative resets are not subject to age or history requirements.

Comment: This being an "administrative reset" is the key point that I'd missed here - thanks!